# What is the operator precedence/order of evaluation in this complex expression, and why is the result -129?

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, order-of-execution

I don't understand in which order actions take place in C++ expressions.

For example:
Why do we get here -129? Can you explain order of actions?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a = 60;
    unsigned c = 88;
    long d = 134;
    int e = -6;

    printf("Reuslt: %ld\n",!a++<sizeof(long double)&(c)|~d--+-e );
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to do this with actions using int k1, k2, k3, ..., kn(where k stands for 1 action) , but i don't understand order of actions yet.

Comment: [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), if it is not specified in this page then it is UB. it will be up to the compiler creator

Comment: Are you sure you have a "C++" question, your code looks like "C".  In C++ the order of evaluation in this case is not speficied. Also for debugging purposes just try to keep the number of side effects on a line limited to 1.  (unless it is really easy to reason about those side effects). Somehow it looks to me like you just wanted to break the compiler ;)

Comment: Anyway, a good rule of thumb is to not write code you don't understand yourself. And this is code nobody *needs* to understand.

Comment: Where did you get this code from? What is the purpose of you exercise? What is your actual assignment?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: @BoP: This is code every C++ programmer needs to understand. An essential debugging skill is figuring out what code formally says according to the language semantics, not what one thinks it says. While it is useful for humans to write code that is clear and whose meaning aligns with how humans naturally interpret it, errors develop due to changes by multiple programmers or other causes, and the presence of a bug is often due to some belief a human has that is not true. So one must learn to analyze code for its formal meaning. Doing exercises such as this is useful for developing that skill.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I hope you mean that any human should be able to say this is a mess, lets write down WHAT we mean in simpler terms. Sometimes the answer really is you don't need to understand a mess if you can replace it with something simpler.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: No, any C++ programmer should be able to explain **exactly** what the code does according to the C++ standard. It is not enough to be able to write code that does what you mean—you must also be able to recognize code that does not do what you want, and that means being able to interpret code according to the formal semantics of the language, not trying to read it like a natural language. The better a programmer is at this skill, the better they will be able to debug, and the more likely they will be to find bugs sooner.

Comment: @EricPostpischil and now you can only hire recruits with 10+ years of C++ development because your codebase is deliberately obfuscated using advanced c++ syntax, good luck explaining that to your HR. good code is one that is easy to change, which means that it is easy to understand, this is why we are no-longer coding in assembly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Again I heartily disagree, good code might not read like human language but it can read like a recipe. I am already happy when developer can write code that is readable, doesn't touch any corners close to the edges of the standard and passes ALL unit tests. 90% of the code is pretty straightforward anyway. And only a minority of developers is needed to write library code (for the rest) and they need to know more. Even after 35+ years C++ experience I still don't know all the standard nooks and crannies and even if I would there are still holes in the standard.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Re “I am already happy when developer can write code that is readable…”: This is not about writing code. This is about reading code. Re “And only a minority of developers is needed to write library code…”: This is not about library code.

Comment: @AhmedAEK: Re “because your codebase is deliberately obfuscated”: No. I did not say it is okay to write code like that. I said it is necessary to understand code like that because the skill is needed for identifying bugs that arise inadvertently. You do not need 10+ years of C++ development to understand the code in the question. You need the skill of reading the code as it is actually written. It is not hard to tokenize a string of characters and parse it according to the grammar. A good programmer should be able to do that with any code instead of reading it naïvely so they can spot errors.

Answer (score 3):

You have ...

```
!a++ < sizeof(long double) & (c) | ~d-- + -e
```

... so let's take what we need from the [C++ Operator Precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and add parentheses to clarify how to interpret the expression:

| Precedence | Operator | Description | Associativity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | `a++` `a--` | Suffix/postfix increment and decrement | Left-to-right |
| 3 | `+a` `-a` | Unary plus and minus | Right-to-left |
|  | `!` `~` | Logical NOT and bitwise NOT |  |
|  | `sizeof` | Size-of |  |
| 6 | `a+b` `a-b` | Addition and subtraction | Left-to-right |
| 9 | `<` `<=` `>` `>=` | For relational operators < and ≤ and > and ≥ respectively | -"- |
| 11 | `a&b` | Bitwise AND | -"- |
| 13 | `|` | Bitwise OR (inclusive or) | -"- |

- **2.** For `a++` and `d--`:

  ```cpp
  !(a++) < sizeof(long double) & (c) | ~(d--) + -e
  ```
- **3.** For `!(a++)`, `sizeof`, `~(d--)` and `-e` (I'm omitting parentheses around `sizeof(type)` here):

  ```cpp
  (!(a++)) < sizeof(long double) & (c) | (~(d--)) + (-e)
  ```
- **6.** For `(~(d--)) + (-e)`:

  ```cpp
  (!(a++)) < sizeof(long double) & (c) | ((~(d--)) + (-e))
  ```
- **9.** For `(!(a++)) < sizeof(long double)`:

  ```cpp
  ((!(a++)) < sizeof(long double)) & (c) | ((~(d--)) + (-e))
  ```
- **11.** For `((!(a++)) < sizeof(long double)) & (c)`:

  ```cpp
  (((!(a++)) < sizeof(long double)) & (c)) | ((~(d--)) + (-e))
  ```
- **13.** There's only `|` left at this point so these go around the whole expression:

  ```cpp
  ((((!(a++)) < sizeof(long double)) & (c)) | ((~(d--)) + (-e)))
  ```

And there is the expression with parentheses to make it clearer what sub-expressions that ties together and you now only have to untangle the mess from the inner parentheses and out.

- For a more in-depth look, see this [C++ Operator Precedence Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77168318/5740428)

Answer (score 1):

I will not provide you the exact answer because this is an exercise and ultimately it is you who needs to solve it. But I will give you the information you need in order to solve it.

Priorities:

- `!`: 3
- `a++`: 2
- `<`: 9
- `sizeof()`: 3
- `a&b`: 11
- `|`: 13
- `~`: 3
- `d--`: 2
- `+`: 6
- `-e`: 3

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

One would expect the order to be left-to-right when we speak about operations of the same priority (except special cases, like assignment, which is not present here and where we go right-to-left), an order overriden by the priorities of the operations. The lower the priority number, the higher the priority of the operation is.

For example, `!a++` will execute the `++` first and only then the `!`, because `++` is of higher priority (lower prio number means a preceding operator). Therefore, you are well-advised to take a pen & paper and draw the [expression tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-tree/).

This will allow you to understand what exactly happens here and in what order. Try to figure this out without peeking at the actual result of the expression and compare the result you get without being influenced with the result you test later using the expression. If the results are matching, then it's likely (but not 100% proven) that you were correct. If the results do not match, then something's off.

If the results are mismatching, then isolate subtrees of the expression tree and evaluate them separately until you get the exact reason(s) that caused the mismatch and then you will understand why you were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [@TedLyngmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77166847/1741542)

- since `a` and `d` isn't used later in the code, you may ignore and remove the post increment and decrement operators

  ```
  ((((!(a)) < sizeof(long double)) & (c)) | ((~(d)) + (-e)))
  ```
- `!a` is `0`

  ```
  ((((0) < sizeof(long double)) & (c)) | ((~(d)) + (-e)))
  ```
- `0 < sizeof(long double)` gives true or `1`

  ```
  (((1) & (c)) | ((~(d)) + (-e)))
  ```
- `c` is an even number, so `1 & c` results in `0`

  ```
  ((0) | ((~(d)) + (-e)))
  ```
- Bitwise `0 | anything` remains anything, so it may be dropped

  ```
  (~(d)) + (-e)
  ```
- `+(-e)` is basic arithmetic

  ```
  (~(d)) - e
  ```
- These were just simple actions, reducing the expression to its minimum. The remaining expression is just `(~d) - e` or `(~134) + 6`, consisting of a difference (or sum) and a bitwise not. For this, you need an understanding of binary arithmetic and [Two's complement (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

---

- Thanks to @user17732522's comment: there's a twist in the [bitwise or](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators): `0 | anything`, see also [Implicit conversions (cppreference)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

  - Since the operands have types `unsigned int` and `signed long`, the first operand (`0`) will be converted to `signed long` and the result is as described in the question.
  - If the operands were `unsigned int` and `signed int` instead, the second operand (`(~d) - e`) would have been converted to `unsigned int` and the result different.

Comment: You ignored the types of the expressions, which are significant. If e.g. `d` was `int` instead of `long`, then the resulting value would be different.

Comment: You're right, I missed this.