# What is the precedence and associativity of operators?

Tags: c++, grammar, operator-precedence, c++-faq

What is the precedence and associativity of operators in C++?

[Who defines operator precedence and associativity, and how does it relate to order of evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20767745/5740428) explains how those properties emerge from the grammar. However, I am simply interested in a list of all the rules.

---

<sub>This question is supposed to be a community FAQ which can be referenced instead of the [cppreference article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).</sub>

Answer (score 8):

## C++ Operator Precedence

| Operator/Expression | Grammatical Rule | Description | Associativity and Arity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `0`, `id`, `this`, `[]{}`, `(expression)`, `(x, ...)`, `requires () {}` | [primary-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#:primary-expression) | Literals, identifiers, fold expressions, requires expressions, etc. These don't really have precedence, but are the building block out of which other expressions are built. | None |
| `::` | [qualified-id](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:qualified-id) | [Scope resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers). `::` is also not an operator strictly speaking, but a way of combining multiple identifiers into a single name. | Left-to-right Binary |
| `x++` `x--` `type()` `type{}` `x()` `x[]` `.`, `->` `static_cast` `typeid`, ... | [postfix-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.general#nt:postfix-expression) | Postfix expressions. Casts like `static_cast` are also classified as a postfix expression, although usually people don't consider it an operator and there is usually no confusion as to its precedence. | Left-to-right Various |
| `++x`, `--x` `+x` `-x` `!x` `~x` `(type) x` `*x` `&x` `sizeof` `co_await` `new` `delete` | [unary-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.general#nt:unary-expression) | Prefix expressions. This also includes C-style casts, `co_await`, `new`, and `delete`, which not everyone expects to be an operator. Note that the operand to `sizeof` cannot be a C-style cast, e.g. `sizeof (int)x` is parsed as `sizeof(int)` followed by `x`. | Right-to-left Various |
| `.*` `->*` | [pm-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mptr.oper#nt:pm-expression) | Pointer-to-member operators. | Left-to-right Binary |
| `*` `/` `%` | [multiplicative-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#nt:multiplicative-expression) | Multiplicative operators. |  |
| `+` `-` | [additive-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#nt:additive-expression) | Additive operators. |  |
| `<<` `>>` | [shift-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#nt:shift-expression) | Bitwise shift operators. |  |
| `<=>` | [compare-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.spaceship#nt:compare-expression) | Three-way comparison operator. |  |
| `<` `>` `<=` `>=` | [relational-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel#nt:relational-expression) | Relational comparison operators. Note that `a < b < c` means `(a < b) < c` and is likely a mistake. |  |
| `==` `!=` | [equality-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#nt:equality-expression) | Equality comparison operators. Note that `a == b == c` means `(a == b) == c` and is likely a mistake. |  |
| `&` | [and-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.bit.and#nt:and-expression) | Bitwise AND operator. |  |
| `^` | [exclusive-or-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.xor#nt:exclusive-or-expression) | Bitwise XOR operator. |  |
| `|` | [inclusive-or-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.or#nt:inclusive-or-expression) | Bitwise OR operator. |  |
| `&&` | [logical-and-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.and#nt:logical-and-expression) | Logical AND operator. |  |
| `||` | [logical-or-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.or#nt:logical-or-expression) | Logical OR operator. |  |
| `a?b:c` | [conditional-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#nt:conditional-expression) | Conditional operator, colloquially called "ternary operator". Note that `b` is parsed as if it was parenthesized, so its precedence doesn't matter. | Right-to-left Ternary |
| `=` `+=` ... `co_yield` `throw` | [assignment-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#nt:assignment-expression) | Regular assignment and compound assignment. Also yield expression and throw expressions. | Right-to-left Various |
| `,` | [expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma#nt:expression) | Comma operator | Left-to-right Binary |

Note that this list equally applies to operator precedence in C.
The C++ rules are a superset of the C rules, meaning that they are the same, just with more operators.

#### Common Examples

| Expression | Parenthesized | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `x + y * z` | `x + (y * z)` | `*` has higher precedence |
| `x + y + z` | `(x + y) + z` | `+` is left-associative |
| `x = y = z` | `x = (y = z)` | `=` is right-associative |
| `x || y && z` | `x || (y && z)` | `&&` has higher precedence (this makes disjunctive normal forms easy to write) |
| `x || y || z` | `(x || y) || z` | `||` is left-associative |
| `x = y ? a : b` | `x = (y ? a : b)` | `?:` has higher precedence, and is right-associative |
| `*x++` | `*(x++)` | postfix expressions have higher precedence |
| `*++x` | `*(++x)` | prefix expressions are right-associative |
| `x | y << z` | `x | (y << z)` | `<<` has higher precedence |
| `cout << x ? y : z` | `(cout << x) ? y : z` | `<<` has higher precedence |
| `x << y + z` | `x << (y + z)` | `+` has higher precedence |

#### See also on other sites

- [C++ Operator Precedence on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)
- [C++ Annex A.5 Expressions, [gram.expr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/gram.expr)